# Removing/renaming files in python

Tags: python, file, rename

I am trying to figure out how I could remove certain words from a file name. So if my file name was lolipop-three-fun-sand,i would input three and fun in and they would get removed. Renaming the file to lolipop--sand. Any ideas on how to start this?

Answer (score 5):

Use `string.replace()` to remove the words from the filename. Then call `os.rename()` to perform the rename.

```
newfilename = filename.replace('three', '').replace('fun', '')
os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it matter what os you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
line = 'lolipop-three-fun-sand'
delete_list = raw_input("enter ur words to be removed : write them in single quote separated by a comma")
for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
print line
```